# Only Single Line Output Coming Instead of Multiple line in C (if/else and for combination)

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop, output

When Trying to run this program only Single line output is shown instead of multiple lines

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    int t,i,a;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    char n[t];
    for(i=0;i<t;i++){
        scanf("%c",&n[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<t;i++){
        if ((n[i]=='b')||(n[i]=='B')) {printf( "BattleShip\n" );} 
        else if ((n[i]=='c')||(n[i]=='C')) {printf( "Cruiser\n" );} 
        else if ((n[i]=='d')||(n[i]=='D')) {printf( "Destroyer\n" );}
        else if ((n[i]=='f')||(n[i]=='F')) {printf( "Frigate\n" );}
    }
return 0;
}
```

My Input was

```
3 
B
c
D
```

Output I received was this

```
BattleShip
```

Comment: Try stepping through your code in a debugger. That will provide wonderful insight.

Comment: input `3Bcd`. or `scanf("%c",&n[i]);` --> `scanf(" %c", &n[i]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf("%c", &n[i])` may read `'\n'`, so `n[0]` is `'\n'` after `'3'`, `n[1]` is `'B'`, `n[2]` is `\n` after `'B'`. Add `getchar()` to read `'\n'` may solve the problem.

```
for(i=0;i<t;i++){
    getchar();   // <--- read additional '\m'
    scanf("%c",&n[i]);
}
```

Comment: The correct solution is to replace `"%c"` with `" %c"`. That way, it doesn't matter how many whitespace characters there are. You just get the non-whitespace characters.

Comment: @user3386109 Thank you, your comment worked